# What is the contemporary term for an "approximating basis"?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, terminology, hilbert-spaces

The term was used in the book [Fourier Series and Orthogonal Functions](https://books.google.com/books?id=cw3DAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=%22approximating%20basis%22&source=bl&ots=rhfUDScg2c&sig=ACfU3U1vyzCLufA1iwOJl1O5GamEa1tpNQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCuvCAys3yAhXtGDQIHfcCCfQQ6AF6BAgSEAM#v=onepage&q=%22approximating%20basis%22&f=false)

and defined on page 56. Here is a screenshot of the definition given:

[image]

But upon googling the term "approximating basis" I only come up with one reference to this book but no definitions from mathematical encyclopedia sites(wikipedia has no entry for this term either). So what is another name for it?

Comment: Glancing at the book in the link, the author says a few pages down that some authors use the term "closed sequence" instead of "approximating basis".  I don't know if that helps or not.

Comment: The typical language would be that the topological closure of the linear span of the set of vectors is equal to the full space.